# SASS/SCSS: Nesting with class as parent and tag as child

Tags: css, sass, nested

For a specified class, I need to apply different rules depending on the tag having that class. The resulting CSS should be:

```
.class {
    display: block;
}
table.class {
    display: table;
}
tr.class {
    display: table-row;
}
td.class {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

In my SCSS, I tried:

```
.class {
    // ...

    table#{&} {
        // ...
    }
    // etc.
}
```

…But it compiles this, which is wrong:

```
.class {
    // ...
}
.class table.class {
    // ...
}
// etc.
```

How can I achieve that?

If I put the `&` symbol before the tag names, then it compiles to `.classtable.class { … }`, which is even worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [@at-root](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sass/directives_atroot.htm)

```
.class {
  display: block;
  @at-root {
    table#{&} {
      display: table;
    }
    tr#{&} {
      display: table-row;
    }
    td#{&} {
      display: table-cell;
    }
  }
}
```